# open App DocumentDirectory with UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uidocumentbrowservc

hi i am developing a documentBrowser ViewController in my app so that user can browse files and folders inside documentDirectoy i was wondering is there any way to implement UIDocumentBrowser to open apps documentDirectory?

Comment: Do you want to open Apple Default "Files" app for browsing files, Folders etc..??

Comment: i dont want to open files app instead i want to gave a view controller inside app to browse files and folders inside

Answer (score 0):

First,Call this function when you want to open DocPicker.

```
 func openDoc() {
            let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes:
                ["public.text",
                 kUTTypePDF as String,
                 "public.composite-content",
                 ], in: .open)
            documentPicker.delegate = self
        }
```

Secondly, Add Delegate in your class.

```
       extension DemoViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            if var url = urls.first {
          //Do something with url.
            print(url)
           }
        }
    }
```